# Copying of structure array to another larger structure array without individual element access?

Tags: c, structure

I  want to copy all the element of small structure array  to larger structure array without copying individual element from the structure my code is below

This question is  asked  here [copy smaller array into larger array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746811/copy-smaller-array-into-larger-array) before but i couldn't find appropriate reply.please help me

```
  struct st 
 {
  int i;
  char ch[10];
 };

 int main()
  {
   struct st var[2]={1,"hello",2"bye"};
   struct st largevar[3];
   strcpy(largevar,var);// this is bad i guss but is there any way to copy without individual element access?
  }
```

Comment: [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using memcpy() as shown below and not strcpy().

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  

    struct st 
     {
      int i;
      char ch[10];
     };

     int main()
      {
          int i =0;
       struct st var[2]={{1,"hello"},{2,"bye"}};
       struct st largevar[3];
       memcpy(largevar,var,sizeof(struct st) * 2);
       for(i=0;i<2;i++)
       printf("%d %s\n",largevar[i].i,largevar[i].ch);
       return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not very far, but the correct function in `memcpy` : `strcpy` copies null terminated strings, `memcpy` copies arbitrary memory blocks :

You could use :

```
memcpy(largevar, var, sizeof(struc st) * 2);
```